# What's the best/recommended way to pass reactive props from components to composables in Vue 3 Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, composable

I'm currently trying out Vue 3's Composition API, using a main app and several composition funtions, aka 'composables'. I studied official docs and several tuts. It seems there are many ways of accomplish the same tasks, so I was wandering what is the best for a couple of things:

- how to pass reactive variables from the main app to the composables? I mean: should I just pass them as the composable's parameters or should I do it some othe way?
- how to use other app's methods or other composables from a composable? :)

Answer (score 4):

1. You could pass any raw/reactive data as composable parameter, but make sure to make the composable function more independent from the component logic (to make it more reusable), you could check [Vuetify 3 composable functions](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/next/packages/vuetify/src/composables) and [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/) to get inspired.
2. Pass them as parameters then run them when needed inside the composable logic.